# how to know the size of iOS application

Tags: ios, react-native

I have developed the react native ios app and my client want to know the size of app to be displayed inside the app.so how can i get the size of app after installing in ipad.I tried react native app-info and device-info but those can be used to get the device info only

Comment: you want to get programmatically means inside the app or else. `know the size of app to be displayed inside the app` plz elaborate this

Comment: i want to get size of app programmatically to display inside the app